# How to download last update files from s3 using boto

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

How to download last uploaded files from s3

This code will get the last updated files in my s3. i just need to download them all at once.

code :

```
import os
import boto3
aws_access_key_id='***'
aws_secret_access_key='***'
client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
import os
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime,timezone
now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
import unittest
files = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='mybuycket')['Contents']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you:

```
from datetime import datetime
currentDate = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,)
print ("Creating S3 Session ...\n\n")
s3 = session.resource('s3')
for file_ in files:
    filedate = file_.last_modified.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    if filedate == currentDate:
        print (file_.key)
        s3.Bucket(bucket_name).download_file(file_.key, "path/to/save/file"+file_.key)
```

Comment: i sorted them, i just need how to download them

Comment: Just split key to get file name as `file_.key.split("/")[-1]` and then pass to `download_file()` to download this file

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: add paranthesis `str(file_.key).split('/')[-1]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198720/discussion-between-thor-is-and-shan-ali).